# How can I add xText editor to Eclipse (e4) RCP Application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, xtext, e4

I've already made a xtext editor (2.5).
I try to use this editor in a part in my RCP application.

I use this code:

```java
Injector injector = MyDslActivator.getInstance().getInjector(MyDslActivator.XTEXT_DSL_MYDSL);
EmbeddedEditorFactory factory = injector.getInstance(EmbeddedEditorFactory.class);
editor = factory.newEditor(resourceProvider).showErrorAndWarningAnnotations().withParent(container);
```

But I got an error

```java
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "com/google/inject/Injector"
```

**UPD1**

The bundle "eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime" has the package "org.google.inject" with another version. The solution was exclude this bundle from the project.

But now I got new error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.embedded.EmbeddedEditorActions.initialize(EmbeddedEditorActions.java:124)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.embedded.EmbeddedEditorActions.<init>(EmbeddedEditorActions.java:119)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.embedded.EmbeddedEditorActions$Factory.createActions(EmbeddedEditorActions.java:63)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.embedded.EmbeddedEditorFactory$Builder.initializeActions(EmbeddedEditorFactory.java:397)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.embedded.EmbeddedEditorFactory$Builder.withParent(EmbeddedEditorFactory.java:233)
```

It happend because the google injector doesn't inject IWorkbench into EmbeddedEditorActions.Factory.

I haven't idea how to fix it.
The e4 application has org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench, bot doesn't have org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your RCP contains the bundle `com.google.inject` only once. Somehow it was loaded in two different versions and both were made available to your DSL plugin.

Comment: You are right. I didn't know that the bundle "eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime" has the package "org.google.inject" with another version.