# Integration of Xtext DSL editors and e4-based RCP

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp, xtext, e4

I am working on RCP application for editing dsl files.

For now I managed to create two editors using [Xtext 2.5](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/index.html) that works fine in Eclipse (validation, cross references, etc.). Also there is e4 based RCP application skeleton with custom navigation tree (files are loaded from remote server not from local workspace).

Now I have to integrate those both of them. Unfortunately I didn't find any up to date tutorials about this topic that works for my case.
Here are links that I tried:

1. This [blog post](http://mdenutshell.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-embed-xtext-editors-within.html) describes integration for Eclipse 3.x
2. [This one](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-up-a-rcp-product-for-a-dsl/) about e4 but version of Xtext is less than 2.5
3. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html) is a lot of information about RCP but I didn't found anything about plugins integration with RCP.
4. There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242845/how-can-i-add-xtext-editor-to-eclipse-e4-rcp-application) but it is not clear for me how to use obtained **editor** or how to get **resourceProvider** instance.

Does anyone have a reference to the relevant tutorial or sample?

Comment: Your reference 2 is for an Eclipse 3.x RCP **not** e4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Eclipse bug [401309](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401309) and various comments in the Eclipse forums XText editors are not compatible with a pure e4 RCP because they rely on lots of code from the 3.x compatibility layer.

You can still create an Eclipse 3.x style RCP, as described in your second reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a comment to [Bug 401309](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401309) where I describe how to make it work.